# ¿Por que se salta líneas de código?

Tags: c++

El problema que tengo es que en el código a la hora de ejecutar se salta líneas de código me refiero a que las primeras instrucciones los ejecuta bien pero después de lo que es `cout<<"¿Desea sacar su Índice de masa corporal? "<<endl;` cuando ingreso escribo el dato y le doy enter ya no ejecuta lo que es el `if` se pasa directamente al `cout<<"¿Tiene alguna alergia?"<<endl;` y nuevamente se salta el otra instrucción sin ejecutar lo anterior.

---

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstring>
 using namespace std ;
 int main ()
 {
char nombre[20],padecimiento[2];
char op,op2,op3;
float peso,altura,IMC;
int edad;
cout<<"Datos del usuario"<<endl;
cout<<"Ingrese solo un nombre: "<<endl;
cin>>nombre;
cout<<"Ingrese su edad: "<<endl;
cin>>edad;
cout<<"¿Desea sacar su Indice de masa corporal? "<<endl;
cin>>op;
if (op=='si')
{
    cout<<"ingrese su peso: "<<endl;
    cin>>peso;
    cout<<"Ingrese su altura: "<<endl;
    cin>>altura;
    IMC=peso/altura;
    
cout<<"Su IMC es: "<<IMC<<endl;

}else;

cout<<"¿Tiene alguna alergia?"<<endl;
cin>>op2;
if (op2)
{
    string alergias;
    cout<<"Espesifique las alergias: ";
    getline(cin,alergias);
}else;

cout<<"¿Padece alguna de las siguinetes enfermedades? \n Diabetes \Asma \Hipertension \n Hipotension \n Artritis \n Migraña \n Higado graso"<<endl;
cin>>op;
if (op3=='si')
{
    string enfermedad;
    cout<<"Espesifique cuales: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,enfermedad);
}
else (op3=='no');
{
    cout<<"¿Alguna de sus familiares padecio de alguna de ellas?"<<endl;
    cin>>padecimiento;
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los códigos escritos en **C++** pueden contener partes escritas en **C**, pero en el caso del código que presentaste, hay una diferencia.

En esta parte de código:

```
if (op == 'si') { }
```

La variable `op` es de tipo char y se está comparando con `si` usando comillas simples. Sin embargo, `si` con comillas simples se interpreta como un número en la tabla **ASCII**

La forma correcta es utilizar [**strcmp**](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), que permite comparar string

```
if (strcmp(op, "si")) {  }
```

Si al comparar la variable op con "si", esta comparación retorna cero, significa que las string son iguales.

```
if (strcmp(op, "si") == 0) { }
```

La función strcmp compara dos stringsy retorna 0 que indica la relación entre ellas.

*código completo*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char nombre[20], padecimiento[2];
    char op, op2, op3;
    float peso, altura, IMC;
    int edad;

    cout << "Datos del usuario" << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese solo un nombre: " << endl;
    cin >> nombre;
    cout << "Ingrese su edad: " << endl;
    cin >> edad;
    cout << "¿Desea sacar su Índice de masa corporal? " << endl;
    cin >> op;
    if (strcmp(op, "si") == 0) {  
        cout << "Ingrese su peso: " << endl;
        cin >> peso;
        cout << "Ingrese su altura: " << endl;
        cin >> altura;
        IMC = peso / altura;

        cout << "Su IMC es: " << IMC << endl;

    }  

    cout << "¿Tiene alguna alergia?" << endl;
    cin >> op2;
    if (strcmp(op2, "si") == 0) {  
        getline(cin,alergias); 
        string alergias;
        cout << "Especifique las alergias: ";
        getline(cin, alergias);
    }  

    cout << "¿Padece alguna de las siguientes enfermedades?" << endl;
    cout << "Diabetes\nAsma\nHipertension\nHipotension\nArtritis\nMigrana\nHigado graso" << endl;
    cin >> op3;
    if (strcmp(op3, "si") == 0) {  
        getline(cin,enfermedad); 
        string enfermedad;
        cout << "Especifique cuales: " << endl;
        getline(cin, enfermedad);
    }
    else {  
        cout << "¿Alguna de sus familiares padeció de alguna de ellas?" << endl;
        cin >> padecimiento;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Utilice [**cin.ignore()**](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) para evitar problemas con la lectura de datos posterior.
getline (cin, alergias) leerá la línea completa de texto hasta el espacio en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Ese es un error común ya que el operador [`>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) no descarta el salto de línea que ingresaste.

Por lo tanto, si inmediatamente lees un caracter con [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) obtendrás el salto de línea o si usas [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) que lee hasta el primer salto de línea que encuentre, obtendrás una cadena vacía.

Para solucionarlo necesitas consumir ese salto de línea. Para ello puedes usar [`cin.ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Es en estos dos lugares donde deberías agregar las llamadas:

```
cin>>op2;
if (op2)
{
    string alergias;
    cout<<"Espesifique las alergias: ";
    cin.ignore(); // <---
    getline(cin,alergias);
}else;
// si no quieres usar else puedes borrar hasta la llave de cierre

...

cin>>op;
if (op3=="si")
{
    string enfermedad;
    cout<<"Espesifique cuales: "<<endl;
    cin.ignore(); // <----
    getline(cin,enfermedad);
}
else (op3=="no");
{
    cout<<"¿Alguna de sus familiares padecio de alguna de ellas?"<<endl;
    cin>>padecimiento;
}
```

---

Por cierto, las comillas simples son para caracteres individuales. Las comillas dobles son para cadenas de texto. En lugar de `'si'` deberías escribir `"si"`.